# Can the Dialog X be disabled from jquery UI 1.7 dialog boxes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When a dialog box pops up there is a "X" in the top right hand corner. I am wondering if there is an option to disable this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the CSS will affect other dialogs.

I'm using the following in the dialog definition, which is executed when it's opened:

```
open: function() {
            $(this).parent().children(':first').children('a').remove();
         },
```

Answer (score 2):

The "X" is placed in an anchor tag with the default `class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all ui-state-focus"`.

You can set the `display` to `none`.

```
a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I use the dialog many times in my site. I only want it in one instance. So I guess I would have to do some jquery selecting and remove it? I thought maybe there was some built in function.

Comment: Yes, since it is only for one instance, even if there's an option, you still need to code it specifically. As far as I can tell from the documentation, there isn't any option to hide/show the default close (X) button.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can pass a 'showclose' logical to the function and let the open method logic decide for you.

```
    open: function(event, ui) {
      if (!showclose)
        $j(ui).find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
      else
        $j(ui).find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
    }
```

That way you can choose to show it each time you call $.dialog.